# Difference between dpkg and kernel architecture?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was going through one of the servers and I found a very interesting thing while installing `.deb` package using Debian.

When I am doing `uname -a`, I get the following output:

```
Linux ip-10-20-1-20 4.15.0-1060-aws #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 21:23:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This shows the system has x86_64 kernel architecture.

When I am doing `dpkg --print-architecture`, I get the following output:

```
amd64
```

So when I want to install the Debian package, I need to need a package with `amd64` architecture, not with `x86_64`.

Can someone tell me why there is a difference between dpkg and kernel architecture?

Comment: it's just a naming scheme. For example, armv7 is armhf in Debian realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86_64 architecture was invented by AMD, not Intel.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

> x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64, AMD64 and Intel 64[note 1]) is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set.

AMD:

> AMD64 was created as an alternative to the radically different IA-64
>   architecture, which was designed by Intel and Hewlett Packard.
>   Originally announced in 1999[14] while a full specification became
>   available in August 2000,[15] the AMD64 architecture was positioned by
>   AMD from the beginning as an evolutionary way to add 64-bit computing
>   capabilities to the existing x86 architecture, as opposed to Intel's
>   approach of creating an entirely new 64-bit architecture with IA-64.
>
> The first AMD64-based processor, the Opteron, was released in **April 2003**.

and

> Intel's name for this instruction set has changed several times. The
>   name used at the IDF was CT (presumably[original research?] for
>   Clackamas Technology, another codename from an Oregon river); within
>   weeks they began referring to it as IA-32e (for IA-32 extensions) and
>   in **March 2004** unveiled the "official" name EM64T (Extended Memory 64
>   Technology). In late 2006 Intel began instead using the name Intel 64
>   for its implementation, paralleling AMD's use of the name AMD64.[31]

When it came out the only possible sensible naming was amd64. Debian never changed this name after.